# Difference Between Assembly and DLL

Tags: .net, assemblies

What is the difference between Assembly and a DLL? While sending the code to a remote client, should a DLL file be sent or should a Assembly be sent (When direct TCP connection is available between two)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.exe

Answer (score 46, accepted):

An assembly is .NET's "minimum unit of deployment". Usually an assembly corresponds to a single file, but it doesn't have to - you can have multiple files, with one of them being the master which knows where all the other bits are.

Single-file assemblies are usually DLLs or EXE files. If you've got a normal class library and you just want to send it to the other side, the DLL is what you want. I'd only worry about more complicated scenarios as and when you run into them :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Sorry if my questions is very naive but from single-file Assemblies you mean like single file as class1.cs. or if that does not seem good could you please explain the term a bit.

Comment: @khalidkhan: No, a single-file assembly is just an assembly consisting of a single file (usually a .dll or .exe file). It could still have come from multiple *source* files. It's very rare that you end up with a multi-file assembly... I can't remember ever using one myself.

Comment: @JonSkeet do the satellite assemblies resulting from resource files count?

Comment: @Gusdor: Pass, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 13):

Well, a .NET dll is an assembly, but .NET exe's can be assemblies as well, so that means that all .NET dlls are assemblies, but the reverse is not true.

You shouldn't be sending actual code to a client.  Rather, you should have the type definitions on both sides (client and server) and send serialized *instances* between the two.

Comment: Except for native DLLs; I don't know that I'd consider those "assemblies" as the term here seems to be more of a .NET usage.

Comment: @BobbyShaftoe: I've updated the answer to specify .NET assemblies.

Comment: @capserOne - Can you please elaborate on "serialized instances"?

Comment: @Pushkar:  Why are trying you push an entire assembly over the wire?

Comment: @Casper - I m trying to implement a Remote Entrusting mechanism which requires mobile modules to be sent to client machines. We cannot send COMPLETE mobile EXE hence decided to send code - again cannot send it uncompiled. So had to compile it to DLL and send. Thought it will be better with assembly.

Answer (score 11):

An assembly is basically a file that contains the MSIL Code and Metadata. 
It is the smallest unit of deployment of .NET applications. 
An assembly in .NET has 2 extensions (.exe and .dll)

dll : dynamic link library. 
So, we can say a dll is an assembly, but an assembly may not always be a dll

In other words, dll is one type of an assembly

Comment: `dll is one type of an assembly`. This is not correct. Assemblies take the form of dll files. An assembly can be a dll file. But dll doesn't have to be an assembly file.

Answer (score 7):

An assembly is a file that contains the compiled code. There are two kinds of assemblies. When you compile your C# program, you're creating an assembly.  Executables (occasionally called "process assemblies") have the EXE file extension. All of the programs in our book are compiled as executables. Those are the assemblies that you can execute; You know, EXE files you can double-click and run. There are also library assemblies, which have the DLL file extension. **DLL stand for dynamic link library**. They're often referred to as class libraries because they contain classes that you can use in your programs.

Answer (score 2):

1. Dll project independent.
2. assembly is project specific.
3. An assembly is a collection of one or more files and one of them DLL or EXE.
4. DLL contains library code to be used by any program running on Windows. A DLL may contain either structured or object oriented libraries.
5. A DLL file can have a nearly infinite possible entry points.
6. Assembly present in bin can have either strong/weak Name and assembly in GAC Should have strong name.

Answer (score 1):

An assembly is the pre-compiled code which will be passed into a the .net JIT Runtime.

It is a machine independent format for the code which can be run by any .net Command Lanuage Runtime.

DLLs and EXEs are the common formats for assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

.Exe
1.These are outbound file.
2.Only one .exe file exists per application.
3. .Exe cannot be shared with other applications.

.dll
1.These are inbund file .
2.Many .dll files may exists in one application.
3. .dll can be shared with other applications.

Comment: Statement 1 is not correct. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024227/can-a-standard-executable-have-an-export-table

Answer (score 1):

This question is not seems valid. Both .dll and .exe are assembly. This are just extention of assembly. Both can contains MSIL code but .exe has single entry point i.e. Main function. But .dll can many entry points.

Assembly is smallest unit of deployment and this can be a dll or exe. This assembly are two types Static and Dynamic. We another type of static assembly i.e known as Satellite assembly which contains resource (images, resource files etc.). You can use strong names for assembly to make it available for globle use by register it in GAC.

Comment: there is a difference between an Assembly and an Library (DLL), and a DLL is no Executable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, "assembly" is a term used for a .NET resource. This not necessarily a DLL. A DLL can be a .NET resource but it can also be a "native" resource as well. An assembly can be packed in a DLL or in an EXE. It just depends on the particular assembly.

If this is like your other question, you need to send the file that contains the assembly. You might be able to do something more complicated but it will be just that.

Answer (score 0):

Any DLL built from a .NET project is an assembly, as is an executable. Assemblies not only contain the CLI code for running under the Common Language Runtime, they also contain full information about the classes and structure of the code in the assembly.

Native DLL's are different in that contain barely any meta-information about the code and resources contained within the DLL. A native executable is almost identical to a DLL.

Assemblies are wonderful because of their modularity and built-in API meta-data.

Answer (score 0):

Assemblies can be organized into a single file where all this information is
incorporated into a single dynamic link library (DLL) file or executable (EXE) file, or multiple files where the information is incorporated into separate DLL files
main functions of an assembly is to form a boundary for types, references, and security. Another important function of the assembly is to form a unit for deployment.

By default, when an assembly is created, it is marked as private.If the assembly
must be shared among multiple client assemblies, it is placed in the GAC, a special Windows folder. To convert a private assembly into a shared assembly, you must run a utility program to create encryption keys, and you must sign the assembly with the keys. After signing the assembly, you must use another utility to add the shared assembly into the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between assemblies and dll is a bit like the difference between hurricane and typhoon. It just depends which ocean does it happen in.

A dll or exe in .NET world is called assemblies. That in the native Windows system are simply called dll or exe.

One other notable difference is that assembly can be dll or executable. Where as in native windows system, we generally think of dll and executable as two different type of items.