# DLL versus Assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, assemblies

what is the difference between DLL and Assembly

---

**Exact duplicate**: [Difference Between Assembly and DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674312/difference-between-assembly-and-dll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DLL is an assembly, whereas an assembly can be a DLL, or EXE.  This was asked yesterday...

Comment: code sharing is done by dll,,where we are putting other than bin is there any option

Comment: But a DLL is not necessarily an assembly. Unmanaged DLLs . . .

Comment: @Kent Boogaart: It's is when you are talking about the .NET Framework.