# Is an EXE just a DLL with a main method?

Tags: c#

I stumbled upon a question that about the exact difference between an assembly, a DLL, and an EXE file.

Is the following statement correct?

> If a DLL has a main method then it becomes an executable? (EXE)

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the [suggested question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674312/difference-between-assembly-and-dll). This question is "true or false: if a DLL has a main method then it is an executable", and the answer is "false". The suggested question is "what's the difference between an assembly and a DLL?"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is the following statement correct: If a DLL has a main method then it becomes an executable?

That statement is incorrect.

Both DLL and EXE files use the PE file format. The difference between a DLL and an EXE is that a DLL has flag 0x2000 set in the Characteristics field of the IMAGE_FILE_HEADER section.

More details can be found here:

[*Peering Inside the PE: A Tour of the Win32 Portable Executable File Format* by Matt Pietrek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)