# gcc '-rdynamic' flag equivalent for MSVC

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, gcc, dynamic-linking

I have a cross-platform project that requires to compile `.so` files with `-rdynamic` in `gcc` ([about -rdynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36692315/what-exactly-does-rdynamic-do-and-when-exactly-is-it-needed)).

Does such an option for `MSVC` exist?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/225432/1917882 and you will reach some ideas on how Visual Studio covers that scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The flag is not needed, because the Windows/MSVC linker model is different. On Windows, the linker uses .LIB files to figure out dependencies, while the OS uses Import Address Tables and Export Address Tables.

The key to getting a a LIB file and an for your Export Address Table exe is [`__declspec(dllexport)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024227/can-a-standard-executable-have-an-export-table). Yes, the name is misleading, but in the end an EXE is a PE-format file just like a DLL.