# Deploying Custom Pipeline Component BizTalk Server 2010

Tags: c#, biztalk, biztalk-2010

Though there are many articles to tell about the Pipeline Component deployment. I dont understand how to do it. I build the solution and I have the .dll file. How do I GAC the Pipeline Component Assembly.

Where do I find the assembly, Is the .dll file is the assembly?I am new to .NET or C# I dont understand any of the terminologies. Can anybody help me with the details.

Comment: Sorry, you say you have the .dll but are asking where to find it?

Comment: I am sorry is the .dll the assembly. How can I GAC that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good way of looking at it (taken from [Difference Between Assembly and DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674312/difference-between-assembly-and-dll)):

> An assembly is .NET's "minimum unit of deployment". Usually an
>   assembly corresponds to a single file, but it doesn't have to - you
>   can have multiple files, with one of them being the master which knows
>   where all the other bits are.
>
> Single-file assemblies are usually DLLs or EXE files. If you've got a
>   normal class library and you just want to send it to the other side,
>   the DLL is what you want. I'd only worry about more complicated
>   scenarios as and when you run into them :)

**In your case**, the DLL is the assembly.
To deploy your custom pipeline component, you would need to

1) Add it to the Global Assembly Cache (use gacutil4)
Check here for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79(v=vs.100).aspx

2) Copy it the Pipeline Components folder (default in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010\Pipeline Components`)

3) Restart the Host Instance (likely BizTalkServerApplication in your case) and deploy your new pipeline which makes use of the pipeline component.